# Transforming from image coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: python, image-processing, homography

I have homography matrix H which is 3x3. I have an image that only contains 0s and 1s to denote whether the pixel is occupied. I would like to take this image and transform it into world coordinates using H.

Is there an easy way to do this using cv2 in python? Otherwise, do I need to convert each pixel location using H?

EDIT:

Here's my code:

```
image = plt.imread('image.png')
obs = np.where(image > 0)
obs_map = np.vstack((obs[0], obs[1]))
obs_map = np.vstack((obs_map, np.ones(obs[0].shape[0])))
obs_map = np.dot(H, obs_map)
obs_map = np.dot(R, obs_map)
plt.scatter(obs_map[0, :], obs_map[1, :])
plt.show()
```

This seems to work but the scale seems off. What value do I need for z value?

H is

```
    1.1048200e-02   6.6958900e-04  -3.3295300e+00
   -1.5966000e-03   1.1632400e-02  -5.3951400e+00
    1.1190700e-04   1.3617400e-05   5.4276600e-01
```

and image consisting of 0s and 1s looks like this:

[image]

and my plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps show images (input and output), and possibly H? It's tricky to say what is wrong without seeing images.

Comment: The output is the same except the horizontal scale is off. I know for sure it's off from ground truth video data which I can't really upload here.

Comment: @Demosthenes It would be great if you can give me hints on how to scale the output image. I'm really not sure why the scale is off. Can I change my homography matrix to achieve this? Can I do something with my z's to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think warpPerspective() might be for you.

Check it out:

[OpenCV 2.4](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))

[OpenCV 3](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))

Comment: Hi, I tried `warpPerspective()` but did not work. I did get it to work somewhat on my own but I am still having trouble. I edited my question.